# Controlling a motor with Alexa enabled WiFi switches

Tags: motor, dpdt

I am looking to replace a DPDT switch, which controls a DC motor, with switches that can be activated using Alexa/over WiFi. For my purpose, the motor needs to spin in both directions, so the polarity needs changing using the switches.

I am wondering if it would be possible to control a motor and reverse its polarity simply using these switches? I am assuming they are SPST switches. I am wondering if it would be possible to create a DPDT switch using a combination of the switches: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Sonoff-Control-Wireless-Compatible-Compatible/dp/B079CL1B5D/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=alexa+switch&qid=1577146354&sr=8-9

Otherwise, if anyone has another solution (or perhaps knows of a DPDT switch on the market that can be controlled via Alexa?), I would be very grateful as I am not an electrical engineer!

Comment: You could use the Alexa switch to control a DPDT relay.

Comment: I suppose you need a 3 position switch F/R/off

Comment: Using individual SPST switches to create a bridge in the way you describe is a *very based idea*. At some point in the lifetime of the system you *will* unintentionally have the wrong set of switches turned on and short-circuit your power supply. Use one WiFi switch to control a DPDT relay for direction and another WiFi switch for on/off.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware that DPDT relays were a thing.